# convert between types image in silverlight wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I need to convert System.Collections.Generic.IENumerable to System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
I select BitmapImage in LINQ syntax

```
var localStore = from n in ((App)Application.Current).global_local_store//this Local_ImagesStore
                               where n.url == url
                               select n.bitmp;//BitmapImage

public struct Local_ImagesStore
        {
            public string url;
            public BitmapImage bitmp;
        }
```

How do I convert this?
I can't do this:

```
var result = new BitmapImage();
result=local_store;
return result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive **BitmapImage collection**.

```
var result = new BitmapImage();
result=local_store.FirstOrDefault();
return result;
```

should work.

Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

**Disclaimer:** i never wrote silverlight for wp7.